# Web sql only works on debug

Tags: javascript, html, web-sql

I'm trying to do the basic operations of a sql database (inserts,updates,edits,deletes) on the chrome's web sql, but my edit and add only work on debug(sometimes) and i don't know why.

I created a form in which i ask the user for the int and string that i want,then I store the values in the localStorage and then using javascript, I try to add them to my web sql.

my javascript

```
function Add(){

name=localStorage.getItem("name");
number=localStorage.getItem("number");

var db = openDatabase('db', '2.0', 'Database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);

db.transaction(function (tx) {

tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Storage (name,number) VALUES(?,?)',[name,number],AddSucess);
});
```

Comment: you sure you want to to use this? It does not have really good support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage

Comment: You probably want IndexedDB instead -> http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/

Comment: I have to, it's a project in which I just have to work with the tools they tell me, it is not up to me

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine, but it doesn't contain table creation. Maybe Storage table has some constraints, like unique name?

But generally, just add an error callback as a fourth argument to executeSql and examine the error that is returned, something like:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Storage (name,number) VALUES(?,?)',[name,number],AddSucess,
               function (transaction, error) { console.log(error.message});
```